# Is there any way to do conference call with dial option using java OriginateAction

Tags: java, asterisk, asterisk-java

This is happening right now

step1: A party Calling using `OriginateAction` and not passing dialoptions like `tTG` so that channel do not have transfer functionality.

step2: B party Calling using `dail()` method where I am passing dailoptions like `tTG`.

```
OriginateAction originateAction = new OriginateAction();
    originateAction.setChannel(ivrChannelStr);
    originateAction.setContext(DEFAULT_CALL_CONTEXT);
    originateAction.setExten("s");
    originateAction.setPriority(priority);
    originateAction.setTimeout(timeout);
    originateAction.setCallerId(processedCLI)
try {
        asteriskManagerService.sendAction(originateAction);
        logger.debug("asterisk call originated");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (callConnectListenersMap.contains(traceId)) {
            logger.warn("Throwing exception for traceID = {}", traceId);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

What I want to acheive is

step1: A party Calling using `OriginateAction` and want to pass dial options like `tTG` so channel can do transfer functionality

step2: same as above

So how should I pass `tTG` in `OriginateAction`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do any options by using Local/ type channel.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-local-channels/

I.e originate to Local/number@out and make in out context any dial command you want with any params.